# Можно ли удалить уже ненужные ресурсы в приложении?

Tags: android, java

Некоторые ресурсы мне нужны только при первом запуске. Можно ли полностью удалить эти картинки?

Comment: Из папки res - нет. Если Вам нужны некоторые ресурсы только при первом запуске - скачайте их отдельно или выложите их отдельным приложением. При старте пользователя нужно будет попросить скачать, а потом, по желанию, удалить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ресурсы - это **статические** данные, зашитые в APK файл. Следовательно, чтобы их как-то видоизменить (удалить, добавить, заменить), необходимо будет как минимум разобрать APK, удалить файлы из директории ресурсов, находящейся в разобранном APK, затем собрать APK заново и подписать его ключом, чтобы Android "дал добро" на установку его в систему.

Чисто гипотетически, наверное, это можно сделать, например, с использованием NDK. Но с этим возникнет столько хлопот, что легче будет просто махнуть рукой или подумать над оптимизацией ненужных в будущем ресурсов. К тому же адекватные разработчики никогда так не делают.